# How do I use the local terminal color scheme when I ssh into a remote server?

Tags: linux, ssh, color-management

I have a local terminal which has a color scheme set up the way I want it. When I ssh into a remote server through this terminal, it adopts the color scheme of the remote terminal within my terminal. Is there any way I can use my own local terminal color scheme instead of the remote one?

Comment: You might consider this a feature, you now know you are on a remote machine.

Comment: @icarus Indeed however I'd also enjoy the option to use my local scheme if it's available, where I have everything fine tuned the way I enjoy it.

Comment: What do you mean by "color scheme"? A custom prompt? If yes, just copy your shell configs to the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using ssh you are logically on the other machine, so your local files are not available right away. Depending on your use-case you can make them available (not so efficient since it always needs to load over the network), copy them (manually or automatically) or use a special tool, that adjusts the output on your machine.
There are some options descibed on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/400522/how-to-use-a-custom-bashrc-file-on-ssh-login), which should get you started.